# Compare dates with null values

Tags: datetime, pandas, timedelta

I have two columns.  I want to check if the difference between them is between 0 and 10 days.  One of the fields often contains null values.

```
df['Diff'] = (df['Dt1'] - df['Dt2'])

def wdw(x):
    if pd.notnull(x):
        if type(x) !=long:
            if type(timedelta(days=10)) != long:
                if x > timedelta(days=10):
                    return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['Diff'].df(wdw)
```

When I run this I get the following error.

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to long
```

When I look at the values of df['Diff'] They all appear to be timedeltas.  Any idea what is going on here?  It seems like creating an indicator based on the difference between two date fields should be easier than this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `df['Diff']` are [numpy timedelta64s](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). You can compare them with [`pd.Timedelta`s](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#time-deltas); see below.

Moreover, you do not need to call `df['Diff'].apply(wdw)`, which calls `wdw` for each value in the Series; you can compare whole Series with a `pd.Timedelta`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dt1':pd.date_range('2010-1-1', freq='5D', periods=10),
                   'Dt2':pd.date_range('2010-1-2', freq='3D', periods=10)})
df.iloc[::3, 1] = np.nan

df['Diff'] = df['Dt1'] - df['Dt2']
print(df)

#          Dt1        Dt2    Diff
# 0 2010-01-01        NaT     NaT
# 1 2010-01-06 2010-01-05  1 days
# 2 2010-01-11 2010-01-08  3 days
# 3 2010-01-16        NaT     NaT
# 4 2010-01-21 2010-01-14  7 days
# 5 2010-01-26 2010-01-17  9 days
# 6 2010-01-31        NaT     NaT
# 7 2010-02-05 2010-01-23 13 days
# 8 2010-02-10 2010-01-26 15 days
# 9 2010-02-15        NaT     NaT

mask = (df['Diff'] < pd.Timedelta(days=10)) & (pd.Timedelta(days=0) < df['Diff'])
print(mask)
```

yields

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: Diff, dtype: bool
```

---

`pd.Timedelta`s were introduced in Pandas v.0.15. Here is a workaround for older version of Pandas which uses `np.timedela64s`:

```
mask = ((df['Diff'] / np.timedelta64(10, 'D') < 10)
        & (df['Diff'] / np.timedelta64(10, 'D') > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am still getting the following error:       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Timedelta'

Comment: Timedeltas are pretty new; they were introduced in version 0.15. I think what I've written is wrong; there should be a way to do the comparison with datetime.timedeltas. I'll edit when I find the answer...

Comment: Okay, I was wrong about being wrong :) You can't do a vectorized comparison against datetime.timedeltas because of the `NaT`s. But instead, you can do a vectorized comparison of `df['Diff']` against a `np.timedelta64`. I've edited the post above to show how.

Comment: Your `x/np.timedelta64(1,'D') <= 10` is cleaner than my `(df['Diff'].values < np.timedelta64(10, 'D').astype('<m8[ns]')`; I've changed my answer to use your comparison -- it generalizes to Series nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This also worked but isn't as good as the answer unutbu provided.

```
def wdw(x):
    if pd.notnull(x):
        if x/np.timedelta64(1,'D') <= 10:
            if x/np.timedelta64(1,'D') >0:
                return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['Diff'].df(wdw)
```

Answer (score 0):

use assign to create a diff date dt1 and dt2 column.  Then use timedelta to get a 0 day and 10 day variable to compare diff then mask the results for output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dt1':pd.date_range('2010-1-1', freq='5D', periods=10),
                'Dt2':pd.date_range('2010-1-2', freq='3D', periods=10)})
df.iloc[::3, 1] = np.nan

print(df)
zero_days=timedelta(days=0)
ten_days=timedelta(days=10)
print(zero_days,ten_days)

df['Diff']=np.empty(len(df))
df=df.assign(Diff=lambda row:  row['Dt1']-row['Dt2'])
mask=(df['Diff'] >=zero_days)&(df['Diff'] <=ten_days)  
print(df[mask])
```

output:

```
  Dt1        Dt2   Diff
1 2010-01-06 2010-01-05 1 days
2 2010-01-11 2010-01-08 3 days
4 2010-01-21 2010-01-14 7 days
5 2010-01-26 2010-01-17 9 days
```